# Прайс-лист с занесением данных в БД Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, база-данных

подскажите пути решения задачи.
Необходимо создать таблицу прайс-листа на сайте WP, чтобы данные цен заносились в БД.
На следующем шаге эти данные цен нужно вывести в другие таблицы на сайте.

Comment: Плагины таблиц же.

Comment: А можно ли в плагинах этих на страницу вывести только 1 столбец из таблицы??

Comment: В некоторых можно.

Comment: Через плагин ACF создаете таблицу, заполняете. Потом функциями выносите на другие страницы. Например делаете все на странице, у которой id = 7. На другие страницы вставляете функцию: <?php the_field('price_car', 7); ?> (для примера: price_car- это поле определенной цены в таблице прайса)